# DataAnnotationsModelValidator class in Net 3.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation, data-annotations

I've seen several examples on hot to implement Custom Validation in ASP Net MVC 2... but I can't find the "DataAnnotationsModelValidator" class in the framework 3.5, neither in System.Web.Mvc nor in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. Could you please point out where I can find it??? Do I need to add an external assembly??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The DataAnnotationsModelValidator class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelvalidator.aspx) is defined in the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly.